# PayPal Subscription Button Coupons

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-buttons

I am using Paypal buttons to subscribe customers to a plan.
I am trying to apply coupons on the Paypal buttons without any luck.

This is the code that generate the Paypal button on the frontend:

```
  paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
        shape: 'pill',
        color: 'blue',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'subscribe'
    },
    createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
            "plan_id": "<PAYPAL_PLAN_ID>"
        });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
       console.log('success');
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

On the documentation I saw that I need to define a javascript variable and I tried

```
var discnt=10;
```

And:

```
var discount_amount=10;
```

None of this variables are working.
Even if the discount will work this way, I want to give the marketing team to define Coupons on their own, and give it to the customers.

Anyone might know how to add coupons to `paypal.Buttons`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `plan_id` , you can pass a `plan` object which overrides the provided plan's details with a different amount, and with a description that reflects the text "discount" or "coupon applied" somewhere.

Parameters for a subscription create call are documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body

So for instance, something like

```
        return actions.subscription.create({
            "plan_id": "<PAYPAL_PLAN_ID>",
            "plan" : {
              "name" : "My Service - $10 coupon",
              "billing_cycles" {
                 /* New billing cycles object with lower amount */
              }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I want the marketing team to just create coupons and then I will add the coupons there if someone put one... This is not helping me sorry :(

Comment: The above is how to communicate the payment details with PayPal; implementing something to manage your coupons is something you'll do on your end. Once you've determined what the details should be for a payment, the above is how to adjust a subscription and send the information to PayPal.

Comment: Still, I can't change the price there.

Comment: Set your price in the billing_cycles. Use your current one as a base, and adjust it to what you want.